# DataBinding to reference types

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, orm

I've got some classes that have properties like this, and they work perfectly because they are very normal:

```
    Public Overridable Property CustomerLastName() As String
        Get
            Return m_CustomerLastName.Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            m_CustomerLastName.Value = Value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I want to change them to work like this (and don't worry about what IField is, suffice it to say it represents a field in a table):

```
    Public Overridable Readonly Property CustomerLastName() As IField
        Get
            Return m_CustomerLastName
        End Get
    End Property
```

That way, you could do Customer.CustomerLastName.PreviousValue, or Customer.CustomerLastName.IsDirty, etc.

But that doesn't bind correctly. Understandable, since databinding is supposed to be a two-way thing, and there's reflection involved, etc.

Of course it can still be a two-way street, I just need to be able to say, "Hey DataBinding! Look over here!"

So. What do I do here?

**Note:** Right now, all I'm trying to do is DataBind to a GridView for display purposes. But I want this to be flexible.

Comment: What kind of data binding are you using?

Answer (score 0):

(Update re edit) If it is just for display purposes, you can probably just set the ToString() on the class that implements `IField`.

---

(original)

No - 2-way data binding wants either `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or an `CustomerLastNameChanged` event. You can shim this into a custom model by implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`, but then you need to write your own `PropertyDescriptor` implementation.

Re `IsDirty` - that is `ShouldSerializeValue` in `PropertyDescriptor` terms.